# woocommerce fetch buyer first and last name after successful payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am working with woocommerce and [paypal for woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/paypal-for-woocommerce) plugin. Once the payment has been successful, the buyer first name, last name and email address needs to be entered in third party software.

Earlier with paypal standard I could get hold of this information as following

```
$fname = $order->billing_first_name;
$lname = $order->billing_last_name;
```

How ever,  first and last name are not coming through the response i get from paypal any more. The order array looks like this

```
WC_Order Object
(
    [id] => 10182
    [order_type] => simple
    [prices_include_tax] => 1
    [tax_display_cart] => incl
    [display_totals_ex_tax] => 
    [display_cart_ex_tax] => 
    [post] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 10182
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2015-03-24 13:10:42
            [post_date_gmt] => 2015-03-24 13:10:42
            [post_content] => 
            [post_title] => Order – March 24, 2015 @ 01:10 PM
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => wc-processing
            [comment_status] => open
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => order_55116250447f7
            [post_name] => order-mar-24-2015-0110-pm
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2015-03-24 13:10:42
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-03-24 13:10:42
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://somewebsite.com/?post_type=shop_order&p=10182
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => shop_order
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 5
            [filter] => raw
        )

    [order_date] => 2015-03-24 13:10:42
    [modified_date] => 2015-03-24 13:10:42
    [customer_message] => 
    [customer_note] => 
    [post_status] => wc-processing
    [billing_email] => abc@xyz.com
)
```

I will really appreciate some help in this. I just need the first and last name, i dont care even if i have to query database for this order

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you submitted a ticket to me directly and I gave you this info, right?

The PayPal system only returns a shipping address.  As such, that's all we were filling in for the WooCommerce order data and the billing info was getting left blank.

We have already added a new option into the Express Checkout settings to use the same address and populate the billing data.  This has not been officially released yet because we have a few other things we need to finish first, but it has been fully merged into our [dev branch on GitHub](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-woocommerce), which is a fully tested branch and is considered stable.  You can [download it directly](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-woocommerce/archive/dev.zip) and use it early if you want to.

Comment: there is something weird going on with your dev plugin, on checkout page, it redirects you to paypal, on paypal once you make payment it redirects you to review order page 'http://somewebsite.com/checkout/review-order/?pp_action=revieworder&token=EC-70W79234BC818721E&PayerID=5UQ3PYJVFZDX6' and then it gives you to button there to cancel order or proceed? whats going on?? are you sure it is stable?

Comment: What you're describing sounds accurate, actually.  The typical flow for Express Checkout is to be redirected to PayPal, login to review details and continue, and then you would be sent back to the site where you're presented with a final review page to finalize the order.  The reason for this is because the application doesn't know the user's shipping address until after they're returned from PayPal and it would then display shipping and tax costs to present a grand total.  If you don't need that you can set the option to skip final review in the Express Checkout settings.

Comment: yes the option to skip final review page is selected and still it takes to the review page

Comment: Do you have any caching or CDN plugins installed by chance?  It might be best if you [submit a ticket directly with me](http://www.angelleye.com/support) at this point.

Comment: Hi, No I do not have any cache and CDN plugin installed and i have submitted the ticket as well, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first and last name from the billing details in WooCommerce.

```
$fname = $order->get_billing_first_name();
$lname = $order->get_billing_last_name();
```